# How to close my pants zipper in a picture through photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a picture in which my pants zip are partially open, wish to close it, how can i use photoshop for this?

[image]

<sub>*[Original image link](https://ibb.co/xztPMZv)*</sub>

Comment: You would need to patch/heal the image. It's practically impossible to be specific without an image to see.

Comment: https://ibb.co/xztPMZv  picture link

Comment: Open zipper isn't your only problem. There's a color border. As soon as one spots it, he sees it this way: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r13gmsyjrn53pep/2Hunt101.jpg?dl=0. You can get accused "you have made this edit"  No facts will be interesting in that phase.

Comment: What should i do then?

Comment: If it's you, then there's no must to do anything. If it's someone else, then duplicate the image layer to have a spare. Take a big , say 72px clone brush, hardness=0, opacity 14% and fade the border. Be sure that the strokes are along the wrinkles One minute work fixes it. No sharp border = no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Using the **Lasso Tool** select the area with the top flap of the zipper
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Win to see the transform frame
- Click the right mouse button and choose **Distort**:

[image]

- Use the **Lasso Tool** + <kbd>Alt</kbd> to unselect the overlapping area
- Deselect all and use the **Stamp Tool** to fix the jean empty areas

Comment: You can give yourself a bigger package at the same time lol...

Comment: +1 for the use of the right-click context-menu in the transform tool!